# Linked brushing possible in R

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

I saw [this](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/linked_brush.html) just yesterday but it's for matplotlib which, as far as I know, is Python only.  This functionality that would be stupendously useful for my work.

Is anything similar available for R?  I've looked around and the closest I've seen mentioned is iPlots/Acinonyx, but the websites for those are a few years out of date.  Do those packages work reasonably well?  I've not seen any examples of their use.

Alternatively, does mpld3/matplotlib/python play well with R?  By that I mean, could I load my dataframes in R, use mpld3/matplotlib/python for exploring my data, then making up final/pretty plots in R?

Full disclosure: I'm a newbie (R is the first programming language that I've really tried to learn since QBASIC as a child...).

Comment: If you aren't tied to a language yet (due to not having learned much R), you could maybe just use Python altogether. It has loads of libraries, and therefore should have all of the functionality of R.

Comment: Yea, if you are just a beginner, why not use Python. I use them both on a daily basis and it is not a bad advice to use Python first; it's arguably easier to learn and only for really specific needs would one turn to R.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what are the specs of a "linked brush plot" it would be easier to help you code it in R. It may exist in R already but under another name. Or it may be very trivial to implement, if we knew what it is.

Comment: Yup, I'm looking into learning Python.  Seeing as I've invested a fair amount of time in R so far and am able to do almost everything I currently need, I thought it would be useful to see if there were an R solution first.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've forgotten how to do linked plots with brushing in R, but I know the capability is there. I use GGobi for that, however - http://ggobi.org/. It's designed for exploratory data analysis using visualizations, and there are R packages to communicate with it and script it.

There's a pretty good book on GGobi - *Interactive and Dynamic Graphics for Data Analysis: With R and GGobi*.

Comment: +1 -- and before it was XGobi, both of which provided linked / brushed plots for over a decade.

Comment: This seems to be the best existing solution to my query.  Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

While R doesn't seem to have anything quite like this yet, I want to note that mpld3 now has a well-defined JSON layout for figure representations, in some ways similar to Vega (but at a much lower level). I'm not an R/ggplot user, but it seems like the ggvis ggplot-to-vega approach could be rather easily adapted to convert from ggplot to mpld3.

Answer (score 2):

The R package [ggvis](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis) will have similar functionality. It is still in relatively early development, as version 0.1 was just tagged a few days ago. (Although that's also true of `mpld3`).

To answer your second question, yes they work reasonably well together. The easiest way to do what you suggested would use the [R magic function](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/R%20Magics.ipynb) in the IPython notebook.

Comment: Definitely looking forward to ggvis.  Thanks for your work on it!

Comment: Ha, wish I could take credit for it! You should be thanking Hadley Whickham and Winston Chang: https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/graphs/contributors

Answer (score 2):

The package JGR provides a java interface for R.  From here, you can call the library iplots.  In your R terminal, type

```
install.packages("JGR");
library(JGR);
JGR()
```

This will open a new window that you can use just like the standard R terminal.
You should now be able to brush using iplots:

```
X = matrix(rnorm(900), ncol = 3);
iplot(X[,1], X[,2]);
iplot(X[,1], X[,3]);
ihist(X[,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at http://cranvas.org/ - it might be somewhat hard to install (especially for a newbie) but it's well worth the effort.